# How to use preg_replace to find and replace words in the link

Tags: php, preg-replace

Here are the two links:

1. `https://m.intl.example.com/detail/detail.html?id=562858877982&amp;abtest=8&amp;rn=ab2d6eacbccdbd3d59b70b38f26c496d&amp;sid=403ef38782392a0c5298d9d7278d9005`
2. `https://item.example.com/item.htm?spm=a230r.1.14.33.a8e813ceFcDRaX&id=522804915538&ns=1&abbucket=9`

I want to extract the value of the "id" in link 1 which is `562858877982`, and then replace the value of "id" in link 2 with the one from link 1.

So link 2 will look like this:
`https://item.example.com/item.htm?spm=a230r.1.14.33.a8e813ceFcDRaX&id=562858877982&ns=1&abbucket=9`

Note that the id from link 1 is dynamic, meaning it can be any number. So the task is to get whatever the value of "id" is rather than the above example id.

Comment: Do you have any PHP code so far? Have you tried anything?

Comment: So far I tried this
$linkone = 'https://m.intl.example.com/detail/detail.html?id=562858877982&amp;abtest=8&amp;rn=ab2d6eacbccdbd3d59b70b38f26c496d&amp;sid=403ef38782392a0c5298d9d7278d9005';


$p = explode('id=',$linkone);

$id = substr($p[1],0,13);

With this , I was able to get the value of id in link one however, how to replace the value of id in link2 with the value of id in link one because the issue. 

My conclusion is that with preg_replace, their is a solution without having to use explode

Comment: It's hard to answer you because you don't show your code, and should put your attempts in an edit to the question not comments :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)  you could use [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) and [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php);

If you pass an array as the second parameter for parse_str you could get the id by using `id` as the array key `$result["id"]`.

To display the link you might use [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) with `%d` when your id can be any number.

```
$url = "https://m.intl.example.com/detail/detail.html?id=562858877982&amp;abtest=8&amp;rn=ab2d6eacbccdbd3d59b70b38f26c496d&amp;sid=403ef38782392a0c5298d9d7278d9005";
$result = [];
parse_str(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $result);
echo sprintf(
    "https://item.example.com/item.htm?spm=a230r.1.14.33.a8e813ceFcDRaX&id=%d&ns=1&abbucket=9",
    $result["id"]
);
```

[Demo Php](https://3v4l.org/10S9O)